# MariaDB cluster and external data feed

Tags: replication, mariadb, galera, xtradb-cluster

I've just finished setting up the 3 nodes mariadb (galera) cluster (let's call the nodes node1, node2 and node3). In order to have the cluster up to date with currently working mariadb database (let's call it dev_db) we created a replication of this dev_db to node1 so dev_db is a master and node1 is a slave. Replication is working properly so node1 is up to date with dev_db. I thought that replicated data to node1 cluster will be able  also transfered to other nodes so that whole cluster will be 'consistent'. 
Unfortunately what is happening is that replicated data from dev_db to node1 is not propagated to the rest of the nodes.

When I add some sample data to node1 I can see that this data is propagated to other nodes (node2 and node3) so cluster is fine.

The question is how to configure this setup so that dev_db will be feeding the cluster with new data so that whole cluster will be up to date.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to enable [log_slave_updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates) so the slave node generates binlog to be used on other nodes.

http://www.severalnines.com/blog/replicate-mysql-server-galera-cluster

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Right now I'm going to setup all the cluster nodes to be slaves and basically all the nodes will be replicating data from dev_db (master).